# error when adding apple pay capability in app

Tags: xcode, applepay

In my app i want to use **Applepay** and i created a `merchant_id` and also

created certificate for **applepay** with *CSR* cerficate and downloaded it

but when i setting capabilities in my app in XCODE it is always showing

following error

In Signing identities

**none of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities features :omc**

In Capabilities

**An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string**

errors are coming

But when i adding capability in older projects it is not showing error and in Simulator also it is not showing error